# The box model and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm noticing something that I've not seen before with regard to IE and the box model.

I have a form tag with a width of 800px and a height of 500px. When I put an h2 tag into this form area, IE reports that the box is taller than the height I assigned (By the height and margin/padding I gave to the h2 tag).

In Firefox and all other browsers, the height does not change. What gives?

```
form #post{
    height:500px;
    width:800x;
}

h2{
    font-size:20px
}

<form id="post">
  <h2>The Header</h2>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using a doctype?

Comment: @BoltClock, Yes. html5. It's weird. I've not seen anything like this before.

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: It seems the CSS given doesn't tally - there's a space in `form #post`. I'm assuming that's a typo?

Comment: Yes, Bolt, it's a typo. Although, even with the typo, it should still work, no?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm. Some typos can make all the difference, but I see you've found the real root of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what happened was that I had a stylesheet being included for IE and there was a margin of 10 pixels which is where the extra height was coming from.

Thanks everyone for looking at this!